# How to combine many ContourPlots using Table?

Tags: list-manipulation, plotting

I noticed that I can plot several functions at the same time using `Table` and `Plot`, like this:

```
Plot[Table[Sin[k x], {k, 0, 3}], {x, 0, 4}]
```

Why doesn't this approach work with `ContourPlot`? I tried something like this:

```
ContourPlot[Table[x + y == k, {k, 0, 3}], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]
```

which unfortunately returns an empty plot.

Comment: `ContourPlot[
 Table[x + y == k, {k, 0, 3}] // Evaluate, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `Evaluate`

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[Table[x + y == k, {k, 0, 3}]], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing. Thank you! Could you please elaborate a bit more why we need Evaluate here, or in which cases in general Evaluate is necessary? (in particular, why it's not necessary with Plot)

Comment: Probably because  `Table` has attribute `Hold All` and  `Evaluate` forces evaluation

Comment: ...and `Plot` doesn't care about `Hold All`?

Comment: @Stephan - `Plot` also needs an `Evaluate` for intended behavior. Compare `Plot[Table[Sin[k x], {k, 0, 3}], {x, 0, 4}]` with `Plot[Table[Sin[k x], {k, 0, 3}] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 4}]`

Comment: I see, thank you!